# How to save objects in state using pinia?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

I want to display the weather of the city and I want them to be added to my state.
I want information to be stored in the state like this

```
city: {[0], [1], ...}
```

but i get only one object

```
city: Object
```

but when i add the weather of the city, it completely changes the content of the city state and it is necessary that the data that comes is added to the array

stores/weather.ts

```
type WeatherStore = {
  weather: OneWeather[];
  city: CityWeather[];
  loading: boolean;
};

export const useWeatherStore = defineStore({
  id: "weather",
  state: () =>
    <WeatherStore>{
      weather: [],
      city: [],
      loading: false,
    },
actions: {
    async fetchCurrentWeather() {
      this.loading = true;
      try {
        const { coords } = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
        const response = await fetch(
          `${weatherUrl}&lat=${coords.latitude}&lon=${coords.longitude}&units=metric`
        );
        const cityRes = await fetch(
          `${cityUrl}&lat=${coords.latitude}&lon=${coords.longitude}&units=metric`
        );
        this.city = await cityRes.json();
        this.weather = await response.json();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    },

    async fetchCityWeather(name: string) {
      this.loading = true;
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${cityUrl}&q=${name}&units=metric`);
        const res = await response.json();
        this.city = res;
        // this.updateCity(res);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    },
},
});
```

Vue Devtool:

```
State
weather:Object
city:Object
loading:false
```

Comment: You need to use `.push()` to add items to an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: i tried that too i got the error
TypeError: this.city.push is not a function
    at Proxy.fetchCityWeather (weather.ts:71:19)

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that in the state I get an object and not an array

Comment: For clarity purposes I would suggest you use plural forms for arrays. So you have an array of cities in your state. In two places in your code, you are overwriting this array with other data (probably a city object), in the lines `this.city = await cityRes.json();` and `this.city = res;`. If you get the data from one city you should do something like `const city = await ...;` and after that you `this.cities.push(city);`. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: i already did what i wanted thank you very much

Comment: Nice, good luck!